# Apache, mod_rewrite and symlinks/aliases

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force the adding of www. if visiting my site.
I've added the following to my site conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/main>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)∞         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]
</Directory>
```

which works great when accessing `example.com`.

But if I make a symlink `ln -s /path/to/somewhere foo` and I try to access example.com/foo I doesn't get redirected to `www.example.com/foo` which is of course as expected since `/path/to/somewhere` is not in `/var/www/main`

Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work with symlinks as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the difference between `Directory` and `Location` directives in Apache. According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html), `Directory` applies to filesystem-space, and `Location` applies to web-space. Try breaking your configuration block up like so:

```
<Directory /var/www/main>
  Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<Location />
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=permanent]
</Location>
```

...in other words, pull the rewrite section out into a `Location` block.

Comment: This redirects but posed a new problem:
The if I go to example.com/sysinfo (which is a symlink) I'm redirected to www.example.com/var/www/main/sysinfo

Comment: Ah, the trick was to skip the Location and Directory all together and put it directly inside <VirtualHost>